# XML sax parser - ignore unbound prefix exception

Tags: android, xml, sax

When parsing an xml file in android, I'm doing like this:

```
try
{
    InputStream is = ...
    MyContentHandler ch = new MyContentHandler();
    Xml.parse(is, Encoding.UTF_8, ch);
}
catch ...
```

The problem is that sometimes the file I'm trying to parse is not well-formed.
In my case, undeclared namespaces may be present.

The data I'm interested in is not inside those tags so I could simply ignore it, but I get an exception of unbound prefix not inside the content handler but in the parser itself; this means that if the exception occurs the entire parsing process is interrupted.

Is there a way of using the sax parser ignoring this kind of error (or namespaces at all)?

p.s. I want to avoid loading all the file in memory as a string and strip namespaces out of it, or having to rewrite the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in another thread.

Instead of using Xml.parse you need to manually instantiate a sax parser through the SAXParserFactory and get a reader.

You can then set the reader features.

Among the available features, one disables namespaces and that does the trick.

Reference -> [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481043/how-can-i-configure-a-sax-parser-in-the-sun-jvm-to-match-the-android-one)